# Create line in canvas word search game

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I created word search game in canvas. Now I want when user select character for determine word draw line for highlight that but this is my results:
 [image]

and

[image]

I want draw line like bellow image:
[image]
And this is my code for this section:

```
    function checkForWord() {

        // get the starting & ending grid-cell
        // that the user dragged across
        var startCol = parseInt(startX / colWidth);
        var startRow = parseInt(startY / rowHeight);
        var lastCol = parseInt(mouseX / colWidth);
        var lastRow = parseInt(mouseY / rowHeight);

        // get the word that the user dragged across
        // by adding the letters from the starting cell
        // to the ending cell
        var word = "";
        var length = Math.max(Math.abs(startCol - lastCol) + 1, Math.abs(startRow - lastRow) + 1);
        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;
        var x = startCol;
        var y = startRow;
        if (lastCol > startCol) {
            dx = 1;
        }
        if (lastCol < startCol) {
            dx = -1;
        }
        if (lastRow > startRow) {
            dy = 1;
        }
        if (lastRow < startRow) {
            dy = -1;
        }
        while (length > 0) {
            // add the letter in this grid-cell to the word
            word += letters[y * colCount + x];
            // highlight the squares that the user selected
            ctx1.save();
            ctx1.fillStyle = "#f5aded";
            ctx1.lineCap = 'round'
            ctx1.globalAlpha = 1.00;
            ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
            ctx1.fillRect((x) * colWidth  , (y) * rowHeight , colWidth , rowHeight);
            ctx1.restore();
            // increment x/y/length for the next letter
            x += dx;
            y += dy;
            length--;
        }

        // reverse the word if dragged backwards
        if (dx < 0 || dy < 0) {
            word.split('').reverse().join('');
        }

        // test if the word is a solution word assuming it's spelled frontwards
        var frontwards = words.indexOf(word.toLowerCase());

        // test if the word is a solution word assuming it's spelled backwards
        var backwards = words.indexOf(stringBackwards(word).toLowerCase());

        // if the selected word matches a puzzle word
        // tell the user they found the word an remove the word from the puzzle
        // if the selected word doesn't match any remaining puzzle word
        // tell the user to try again
        if (frontwards >= 0 || backwards >= 0) {
            var index = Math.max(frontwards, backwards);
            $results.text("You just found: " + words[index]);
            words.splice(index, 1);
            if (words.length > 0) {
                var remainingWords = "Find:"
                for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    remainingWords += " " + words[i];
                }
                $puzzle.text(remainingWords);
            } else {
                $puzzle.text("Congratulations...");
                $results.text("You found all the words in the puzzle!");
            }

        } else {
            if (words.length > 0) {
                $results.text("Sorry...Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

How I can do this work please help!

Comment: Please show a snippet of code that you have a problem with. What have you tried, what failed?

Comment: Question now is edited and added code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example Word Search using rounded semi-transparent stokes for highlighting:

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY,endX,endY;

var rows=7;
var cols=7;
var cellWidth=40;
var cellHeight=40;

var letters = ['g', 'b', 's', 'i', 'c', 'e', 'n', 'o', 'b', 'u', 'w', 'v', 'r', 'd', 'o', 'k', 'i', 't', 'o', 'n', 'd', 'd', 't', 'm', 'c', 't', 'a', 'a', 'h', 'a', 'p', 'y', 's', 'e', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'z', 'b', 'z', 'i', 'r', 'p', 't', 'a', 's', 't', 'e', 's'];

var solutions=[];
solutions.push({start:{col:0,row:0},end:{col:0,row:3},color:'gold',word:'butter',isSolved:false});
solutions.push({start:{col:1,row:0},end:{col:6,row:5},color:'purple',word:'good',isSolved:false});
solutions.push({start:{col:0,row:6},end:{col:6,row:0},color:'green',word:'popcorn',isSolved:false});
solutions.push({start:{col:1,row:6},end:{col:6,row:6},color:'blue',word:'tastes',isSolved:false});
solutions.push({start:{col:3,row:1},end:{col:0,row:4},color:'red',word:'with',isSolved:false});

ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineWidth=20;
ctx.font='14px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

drawLetters(letters);

highlightSolvedWords();

function testSolution(){
  var col0=parseInt(startX/cellWidth);
  var row0=parseInt(startY/cellHeight);
  var col1=parseInt(endX/cellWidth);
  var row1=parseInt(endY/cellHeight);
  for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
    var s=solutions[i];
    var index=-1;
    if(s.start.col==col0 && s.start.row==row0 && s.end.col==col1 && s.end.row==row1){
      index=i;
    }
    if(s.start.col==col1 && s.start.row==row1 && s.end.col==col0 && s.end.row==row0){
      index=i;
    }
    if(index>=0){
      solutions[index].isSolved=true;
      highlightWord(solutions[index]);
    }
  }
}

function highlightSolvedWords(){
  for(var i=0;i<solutions.length;i++){
    var solution=solutions[i];
    if(solution.isSolved){
      highlightWord(solution);
    }
  }
}

function drawLetters(letters){
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  for(var i=0;i<letters.length;i++){
    var row=parseInt(i/cols);
    var col=i-row*cols;
    ctx.fillText(letters[i],col*cellWidth+cellWidth/2,row*cellHeight+cellHeight/2);
  }
}

function highlightWord(word){
  var x0=word.start.col*cellWidth+cellWidth/2;
  var y0=word.start.row*cellHeight+cellHeight/2;
  var x1=word.end.col*cellWidth+cellWidth/2;
  var y1=word.end.row*cellHeight+cellHeight/2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
  ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.strokeStyle=word.color;
  ctx.globalAlpha=0.25;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalAlpha=1.00;
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUpOut(e){

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isDown=false;

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  endX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  endY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  testSolution();

}


$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUpOut(e);});
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>MouseDown at start of word. MouseUp at end of word.</h4>
<h4>Find: Popcorn tastes good with butter</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: If you inspect element this page you see your codes error!

Comment: @Troy, You seem to have forgotten the links you intended to go with your comments. Anyway, the code snippet in my answer works fine for me. For example, press the mousebutton down over the top left "g" and release the mousebutton over the "d" which is three cells below the g. The word "good" will be highlighted.

Comment: Yes, That's true, But I want when mouse move draw line, and this line also draw for any character or word.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not seeing that "highlight anything" happening for my snippet. For example, if I attempt to select the "g-b-s-i" at the top of the puzzle, it will not highlight because "g-b-s-i" is not in the solution set. Anyway, I wasn't really trying to change your original code logic, I just wanted to answer your specific question here about how to highlight words with different-colored, semi-transparent, round-capped strokes. I think I've successfully done that! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi Mr @markE, How I can draw line for every character select on canvas like above your answer question?

Comment: @Farshid. This example draws a line through every character in each valid word.

Comment: How I can draw this line for each word?

Comment: I know, but I want draw it for also invalid words, please help me!

Comment: To highlight while the user drags, you will need to redraw the letters, solved-word-highlights & the temporary drag-line with each `mousemove` event. All the pieces to do this are already in the existing code. With each `mousemove`: (1) clear the canvas, (2) drawLetters, (3) highlightSolvedWords, (4) calculate the line starting and ending cell positions based on the starting & current mouseX,mouseY (see code in highlightWord to convert mouse positions to cell positions) , (5) use the code from highlightWord to draw a temporary highlight from the starting to ending cell positions. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try **strokeStyle** with  ***rgba*** and **lineCap** = 'round'

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 200);
context.lineTo(400,400);
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,0.5)';
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.stroke();
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/musthaan/0df6Lbfy/

Comment: I add your code in my project but it's not properly work http://jsfiddle.net/testtest/3bbzrgoz/